# How to remove a user from an OpenLDAP group using Python ldap3 module?

Tags: linux, ldap, python, openldap

I'm trying to manage group memberships for users in an OpenLDAP directory using the Python `ldap3` module. The [docs for the Delete operation](https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/delete.html#) show how to remove a user from an `OU`, however I simply want to remove `memberUid` entries in `POSIX` group objects, as well as the `member` entries in `groupOfName` objects.

I tried to use the `c.delete()` call to do this without success. Is there another way?

My group object looks like this:

```
dn: cn=sales,ou=groups,dc=mycorp,dc=net
cn: sales
gidNumber: 12009
objectClass: posixGroup
objectClass: top
memberUid: milton
memberUid: trebor
memberUid: yggdrasil
```

The only incantation (obviously wrong) I can come up with is this:

```
   conn.delete ('memberUid=milton,cn=sales,ou=groups,dc=mycorp,dc=net')
```

The result is:

```
ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPNoSuchObjectResult: LDAPNoSuchObjectResult - 32 - noSuchObject - cn=sales,ou=groups,dc=mycorp,dc=net - None - delResponse - None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it helps someone else, instead of `conn.delete` I had to use the `modify` method with the `MODIFY_DELETE` operation, while pointing at the group `DN` with the `memberUid` attribute and member to remove.

```
result = conn.modify("cn=sales,ou=groups,dc=mycorp,dc=net", {'memberUid': [(MODIFY_DELETE, ['milton'])]})
```